# How do I copy an object and it's prototype chain without calling its constructor function?

Tags: javascript, copy, coffeescript, prototype-oriented

How do I copy an object and it's prototype chain without calling its constructor function?

In other words, what would the function `dup` look like in the following example?

```
class Animal
  @sleep: -> console.log('sleep')
  wake: -> console.log('wake')
end
class Cat extends Animal
  constructor: ->
    super
    console.log('create')

  attack: ->
    console.log('attack')
end

cat = new Cat()         #> create
cat.constructor.sleep() #> sleep
cat.wake()              #> wake
cat.attack()            #> attack

dup = (obj) ->
  # what magic would give me an effective copy without
  # calling the Cat constructor function again.

cat2 = dup(cat)          #> nothing is printed!
cat2.constructor.sleep() #> sleep
cat2.wake()              #> wake
cat2.attack()            #> attack
```

As much as it pains me to look at, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaCw8/4/) of the example.

I'd also need the properties despite only using functions in my example.

Comment: You know that jsFiddle supports CoffeeScript now, right? Use the **Panels** menu on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function dup(o) {
    return Object.create(
        Object.getPrototypeOf(o),
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(o)
    );
}
```

Which relies on the ES6 `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`. You can emulate it. [Taken from pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd/blob/master/src/pd.js#L46)

```
function getOwnPropertyDescriptors(object) {
    var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object),
        returnObj = {};

    keys.forEach(getPropertyDescriptor);

    return returnObj;

    function getPropertyDescriptor(key) {
        var pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, key);
        returnObj[key] = pd;
    }
}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors = getOwnPropertyDescriptors;
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tSXam/1/)

Converting this into coffeescript is left as an exercise for the user. Also note that `dup` shallow copies own properties.

Comment: This looks great! I believe this will work, just one hiccup. I seem to be getting an object which inherits from the on I passed in. This is slightly different than copying the exact prototype chain. Is there a correct way to refer to the super object after I've duped?

Comment: Got it. ``Object.getPrototypeOf(cat)``.

Comment: presumably the duplicate will share any "local" variables that were lexically bound in the scope of the original object's methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the special `__proto__` member, which is available in every object and is a pointer to the prototype of the object's class. The following code is in pure javascript:

```
function dup(o)
{
    var c = {};

    for (var p in o)
    {
        c[p] = o[p];
    }
    c.__proto__ =  o.__proto__;

    return c;
}
```

Comment: ``__proto__`` is deprecated and will be removed.